How to keep the challenge files for Certbot/Letsencrypt to upload them to Docker?
I want to do something like certbot renew --webroot, except the Node server is running in Docker. I want to take the challenge files that Certbot downloads and copy them to the Docker container. I know I could just use a Docker volume, but my Docker Compose file is already complicated and I'd prefer not to add more to it.
I.e. I'm trying to do the following:
certbot renew --webroot -w path --keep-challenge-files || true
docker cp path container:path
certbot renew --webroot -w path

The keep-challenge-files flag doesn't exist, is this possible?
